# Unsafe dictionary value assignment by key of a union type in strict mode

Tags: typescript

TypeScript looks unsound when a dictionary value is assigned by key of a union type, even when using the latest typescript@3.4.5 and strict mode.

Is it a known issue?  Can someone point me to a related bug report?

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

test.ts

```js
interface A {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}

interface B {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}


function someFunction(a: A, b: B, field: 'a'|'b'): void {
  // ...
  // A lot of unrelated code
  // ...
  b[field] = a[field];
  // ...
  // A lot of unrelated code
  // ...
}


const a = { a: 1, b: '1' };
const b = { a: '2', b: 2 };
someFunction(a, b, 'a');
// type of B.a is string, but in this instance a number is assigned
// and TypeScript fails to warn about it even in strict mode :-(
console.log(typeof b['a']);
```

Running this code with typescript@3.4.5 and ts-node (`ts-node test.ts`) yields

```
number
```

Comment: The fun part is you don't even need two objects to make this happen, it seems like a['a'|'b'] is number|string and so it will let you assign either a number or a string to it even though we know that that's incorrect. Seems like when assigning it should be asserting that the value is number&string, not number|string? (Edit: Oh, looks like they've already got that all figured out based on the answer below, ignore me.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is unsound and is a known hole in type system that is going to get fixed in 3.5 with this [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769). From the PR:

> With this PR we improve soundness of indexed access types in a number of ways:
>
> - When an indexed access `T[K]` occurs on the source side of a type relationship, it resolves to a union type of the properties selected by `T[K]`, **but when it occurs on the target side of a type relationship, it now resolves to an intersection type of the properties selected by `T[K]`**. Previously, the target side would resolve to a union type as well, which is unsound.
> - Given a type variable `T` with a constraint `C`, when an indexed access `T[K]` occurs on the target side of a type relationship, index signatures in `C` are now ignored. This is because a type argument for `T` isn't actually required to have an index signature, it is just required to have properties with matching types.
> - A type `{ [key: string]: number }` is no longer related to a mapped type `{ [P in K]: number }`, where `K` is a type variable. This is consistent with a string index signature in the source not matching actual properties in the target.
> - Constraints of indexed access types are now more thoroughly explored. For example, given type variables `T` and `K extends 'a' | 'b'`, the types `{ a: T, b: T }[K]` and `T` are now considered related where previously they weren't.

**Note**: Highlighted the bit probably relevant for this issue.
You can try it out on 3.5 now by installing it with `npm install typescript@next` and you will get the expected error.